# Chromebook boots into Chrome OS instead of Ubuntu

Tags: chromebook, chromeos

When I turn off my chrombook running ubuntu 13.10 and turn it back on it always boots back into chrome OS. How can I get it so that when i turn my acer c7 chromebook running ubuntu 13.10 off then turn it back on it wont boot back into chrome OS?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you dual-booted ubuntu and chrome os? If that's the case, just hold F8 on boot and select Ubuntu instead of chrome os.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Acer C729 chromebook. The my knowledge, there is NO WAY to for the "legacy boot" as the default forever.  There is an error boot screen and we need to recognized that either 
a) pressing "CNTL-d" - ChromeOS developer mode
b) pressing "CNTL-l" (el) - Legacy boot mode
is needed.  If you've enabled legacy boot, of course.

So - on a plain C7 chromebook - I don't know the answer. If you clarify the exact model, someone else may be able to help.